# vuejs application doesnt work toggle code integrated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

M new to vue m creating a vertical navigation bar on click of menu icon the navbar must toggle
my menu icon code

```
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info [collapsed?'':'sidebar']"  >
    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
    </button>
```

on toggle of the menu icon i wanna show the nav sidebar

```
   <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    </nav>
```

my vue code

```
  new Vue({
   e1:'#app',
   data:{
       collapsed:true
   }
})
```

it doesnt display any thing m new to vue can anyone help me out whats happening

**Updated code**

Position.vue

```
  <template>
   <div class="wrapper">
     <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar" v-if="showSidebar">  
       <ul class="list-unstyled component">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubMenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubMenu">
                    <li class="dropdown-menu-mn">
                        <a href="#">Home1</a>
                        <a href="#">Home2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>                                                 
        </ul>
    </nav>        
        <div id="content">
            <nav>
                <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" @click="toggleSidebar">
                          <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>        
    </div>  
   </template>

  <script>
    new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: {
   showSidebar: false
    },
    methods: {
  toggleSidebar: function() {
     this.showSidebar = !this.showSidebar;
  }}})            
  </script>
```

**update script tag**

```
    <script>
    export default{
    data() {
   showSidebar: false
    },
     toggleSidebar(){
     this.showSidebar = !this.showSidebar;
    } };   
   </script>
```

but it still doesnt work. now ony the menu button appears but the toggle doesnt work. can anyone lemme know where m going wrong

Comment: Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/8ln5nk9nm9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@click` listener on the button

```
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" @click="toggleSidebar">
       <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
    </button>
```

Add `v-if` directive on the sidebar that will toggle the visibility of the sidebar

```
   <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar" v-if="showSidebar">
    </nav>
```

Add `method` to handle the *click* event `methods: toggleSidebar ....` and toggle the value which is used in the `v-if` directive

```
  new Vue({
   el:'#app',
   data: {
       showSidebar: false
   },
   methods: {
      toggleSidebar: function() {
         this.showSidebar = !this.showSidebar;
      }
   }
  })
```

Comment: i get  Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined . i have update my code

Comment: @Tested Make sure you have added `script` tag for `Vue` at your `html` and before your using `Vue` any where in your file.

Comment: @JunedLanja i did add have updated my code for now i dont get that reference error but then it displays nothing